Como persistir dados de um model com um campo de N valores padrões?
Eu tenho a tabela Produtos, Categoria e PordutosCategoria(que é muitos para muitos);
So que, Categoria não tem quantidade fixa, e por isso no Formulário de cadastro ele é criada dinamicamente com uso de ViewBag dentro de um foreach.
@if (ViewBag.marcaVb != null)
{
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.marcaVb)
{
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
             value=@item.Key id="@item.Key">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
            <p>@item.Value.ToString()</p>
            <p>@item.Key</p>
        </label>
    </div>
}
<a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-info" asp-controller="Marca" 
     asp-action="CreateMarca">Criar nova marca</a>
}

Eu não sei como esses dados retornam para a Controller,(Acho que deva ser algum tipo de List) então não sei como salvar esses dados no BD.

olá Luiz, ta um pouco confusa a sua pergunta... algumas notas: 1) não coloque ids fixos em blocos com laços (foreach por exemplo), os ids devem ser únicos e aqui pode criar N elementos com o mesmo id, não vai funcionar bem. 2) a tua action espera um objeto "CreateCategoriaViewModel", isso não está na pergunta, na tua view, não encontro as propriedades "Nome" e "Descricao", logo não vai chegar nada... está mesmo confuso, talvez deva criar a parte da categoria como uma Partial View, procure a respeito, tem muitos exemplos na internet e deve servir para o que vc quer fazer

Obrigado @RicardoPontual! Agradeço a dica. Mas eu acho que vou cair na mesma.
Minha duvida é "Como eu faço para salvar no BD as opções que foram selecionadas no foreach(Que eu ja arrumei com sua dica)?"
Minha dificuldade é:
-O foreach cria uma lista de opções;
-Não sei como essas opções retornam para o controle;
-Dai não sei como salvar esses valores no banco.
Se eu fizer uma PartialView, eu vou colocar o foreach novamente e vou cair na minha dificuldade novamente.
Mas obrigado, ja vou alterar as coisas que você me falou..Valeu
